# Does Cache.Insert override the previous AbsoluteExpiration?

Tags: asp.net, caching

If i have an item that already exists in my `ASP.NET Cache` ... and I just wish to *update the value* of that cached item .. not the `Absolute Expiry` value, or `Cache Dependencies`, etc.. nothing else BUT the value ... can I use `Cache.Insert`?

If not, is there anyway I can retrieve all those values for the cached item .. and then re-use them when I do the `Cache.Insert`?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create functions to handle adding fresh value or updating the existing one as follows:

```
private static Cache cachingControl;

public void UpdateToCache(object key, object updateValue)
{
    try
    {
        if (key != null)
        {
            cachingControl.Remove(key);
            AddToCache(key, updateValue);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //**ToDo[Logging]** Code for logging
    }
}

public void AddToCache(object key, object saveValue)
{
    try
    {
        if (key != null)
        {
            cachingControl.Insert(key, saveValue,null,System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //**ToDo[Logging]** Code for logging
    }
}
```

Here you can use AddToCache function to insert new values and UpdateToCache function to update new values to existing key.(This basically involves in removing the existing key and adding it again with updated values.)

There is no direct way to update the existing values.

Answer (score 0):

The `Cache.Insert` overload that takes just the key and object will simply use default values for the caching behaviour.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bawy15w.aspx):

> Inserts an item into the Cache  object with a cache key to reference its location, using default values provided by the CacheItemPriority  enumeration.

You'd be best to create your own helper class to store the values for you as I don't believe there's a way to get at the cached item's behavioural properties.

Comment: So it's an over-write? I was thinking as much.

Comment: Yes, `Cache.Insert` simply overwrites the `Cache` key. I don't know of any way to get at the caching properties so your wrapper would need to take care of that.